# Updating Enemy Health bar in unity 2d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Why is this connecting all the health bars of my enemies together, even though their actual health is decreasing at its specified rate?

```
public class FillHealth : MonoBehaviour
{
    Image HealthBar;

    private NormalMonster normalMonster;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        HealthBar = GetComponent<Image>();
        normalMonster = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Normal Monster").GetComponent<NormalMonster>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        UpdateHealthLeft();
    }

    public void UpdateHealthLeft()
    {
        if (normalMonster.healthLeft > 0)
        {
            HealthBar.fillAmount = normalMonster.healthLeft / normalMonster.setHealth;
        }
    }
}
```

This is the script that is being referenced in FillHealth. As far as I understand it, since the variable isn't static, then the values should not be shared. It should find fill the health bar for each individual enemy.

```
public class NormalMonster : MonoBehaviour
{
    private float _normalSpeed = 2f;

    private float _BaseHealth = 20f;
    private float _HealthModifier;
    public float setHealth;
    public float healthLeft;

    

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        UpdateHealth();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        NormMonMov();
    }

    public void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.tag == "Arrows")
        {
            healthLeft -= Arrows.Damage;
            Destroy(other.gameObject);

            if (healthLeft <= 0f)
            {
                Destroy(this.gameObject);
                EarnedGold.earnedGold += 7;
                Spawn_Manager.enemyCount--;
            }
        }
    }

    public void UpdateHealth()
    {
        if (StageMode.StageLvl > 5)
        {
            _HealthModifier = (StageMode.StageLvl * 0.01f) * _BaseHealth;
            setHealth = Mathf.Round(_BaseHealth + _HealthModifier);
        }
        else
        {
            setHealth = _BaseHealth;
        }
        healthLeft = setHealth;
    }



    public void NormMonMov()
    {
        transform.Translate(Vector3.left * _normalSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        transform.position = new Vector3(Mathf.Clamp(transform.position.x, -7.0f, 10), transform.position.y, 0);
    }


}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated for this guy who just start playing with unity this weekend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the issue is with `normalMonster = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Normal Monster").GetComponent<NormalMonster>();`

If you have two Monsters
Both have two scripts attached, FillHealth and NormalMonster
Both the "FillHealth" scripts look for the *FIRST* gameobject in the scene that has a script with tag NormalMonster so both monsters are pointing to the exact same NormalMonster script (the first in the list)

Change "GameObject" capital G to "gameObject" lower case g

Still not the best way to code this, but that may work I think

Comment: I only started playing with Unity, or game design of anykind this weekend. What would be best practice for identifying the game object I want? If that is a much deeper conversation, no need to get into because I will do somemore research. Thank you!

Comment: I am not an export, but I found that the following works well, ensures your script is pointing to the asset you expect and will run with error that points exactly where the fault is:
`[SerializeField]
 private Image theImage;`
A static link you then drag your asset to in the editor

Comment: Instead of finding the NormalMonster component you should add NormalMonster field in the inspector and drag the one you want to modify there. I.e. make NormalMonster publuc, remove the find row from start, and drag NormalMonster component in the inspector.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of getting the image, get the rect transform, like this

```
public RectTransform healthBar;
```

and change the length with:

```
healthBar.sizeDelta = new Vector2(normalMonster.healthLeft,healthBar.sizeDelta.y);
```

Comment: also, instead of GetComponent<Image>, do GetComponent<RectTransform>